# How to synchronize access to class field in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

There is a variable in the class, which is actively used by multiple threads. For example:

```
public class A {
    private int magicVar;

    private void someMethod() {
        // some operations with magicVar
    }

    public synchronized void somePublicMethod() {
        // some operations with magicVar
    }

    private class B extends Thread {

        @Override
        private void run() {
            // some operations with magicVar
        }

    }
}
```

How to organize access to the variable in this case? To describe private synchronized setter and getter? Or to mark this field as violate?

Comment: Synchronization is a hard topic. You will have a better starting if you read Java Concurrency in Practice.

Answer (score 1):

That fully depends on how you plan to use your class. Synchronization is not an implementation detail, it is part of design.

Consider using `AtomicInteger` when protecting access to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Making the field volatile will ensure visibility across the threads but if you are making operations like

```
a = a + 2;
```

which is a compound operation, not an atomic one. To make the latest changes to your field visible to all threads and perform atomic operations you can mark both someMethod() and somePublicMetod() as syncronized.

Either that or make finer synchronized blocks having a lock object

```
Object lock = new Object(); // make this an instance variable
// ...
// then each time  you need to make operations with your contended field you can do 
synchronized(lock) {
    // make changes to your contended field
}
```

Comment: In the case of int a; a = a + 2;` you could also make `a` be an `AtomicInteger` which handles increments appropriately.

Comment: It's not super nice to downvote a fellow answer, but it's important: you *definitely* should use an `AtomicInteger` before using `synchronized`, and you *definitely* should not give the advice to use `synchronized` as a go-to, general threadsafe pattern. It's rarely the right thing to do and using freely leads to rampant deadlocks.

Comment: @user3149106 clearly doesn't understand the basics of multi-thread programming so I recommended the use of synchronized which is safer for newbies, all acceses that involves shared resources will work fine. If you run into deadlocks then you code is complicated enough a simple question in SO won't help you with the basics. And if you use AtomicInteger you can still run into using it in compound operations which will still end up in 'synchronization' problems. As a side note. I also recommended the book of Java Concurrency in Practice.